# Backtrace HTTP request over few modules when using FRIDA

Tags: ios, frida, api

I am in the process of reverse engineering an IOS IPA using HOPPER and FRIDA. First, I started with POSTMAN, which records the app's HTTP requests. What I find interesting is that the app uses a so-called "device check token" in its login header. This is dynamically generated when a login is performed.

Second, I recorded the requests with FRIDA Trace and added this code to the automatically generated tweak file "dataTaskWithRequest_completionHandler_.js":

```
...      
onEnter(log, args, state) {
        log("URL: " + ObjC.Object(args[2]).URL().absoluteString());
        log('NSURLSession called from:\n' +
            Thread.backtrace(this.context, Backtracer.ACCURATE)
            .map(DebugSymbol.fromAddress).join('\n') + '\n');
      },
...
```

My guess was to get the functions involved in generating this token. So the trace returns

```
/* TID 0x103 */
  3260 ms  -[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:0x28035c760 completionHandler:0x280e6c840]
  3260 ms  URL: https://mobile-api.rewe.de/mobile/customer/login?includePickupStations=true
  3260 ms  NSURLSession called from:
0x104bc9e80 RxClient!0xfde80 (0xfde80)
0x1010f7d24 RxSwift!0x2bd24 (0x2bd24)
0x1011229a0 RxSwift!0x569a0 (0x569a0)
0x10111b86c RxSwift!0x4f86c (0x4f86c)
0x1011229a0 RxSwift!0x569a0 (0x569a0)
0x1010de674 RxSwift!0x12674 (0x12674)
0x1010deb5c RxSwift!0x12b5c (0x12b5c)
0x101122e10 RxSwift!0x56e10 (0x56e10)
0x1010f80fc RxSwift!0x2c0fc (0x2c0fc)
0x101122a7c RxSwift!0x56a7c (0x56a7c)
0x10113ed88 RxSwift!0x72d88 (0x72d88)
0x10113ef48 RxSwift!0x72f48 (0x72f48)
0x10113698c RxSwift!0x6a98c (0x6a98c)
0x1011368fc RxSwift!0x6a8fc (0x6a8fc)
0x1011357b0 RxSwift!0x697b0 (0x697b0)
0x101135384 RxSwift!0x69384 (0x69384)
```

Now I'm stuck at this point and I'm just running out of ideas on what to do next. I prefer a way to step through these functions (Debug). I think it started with "0x101135384 RxSwift!0x69384 (0x69384)" but I don't know how to do this.

Is there a better solution to get the token algorithm?

Comment: I recommend you to also perform a static analysis on the app as it will help you to understand what functions to hook. Additionally you should consider checking the correspondent Android app as Android apps are usually easier to decompile and understand e.g. using Jadx (assuming that it also uses the device check token system).